# How to get the signed_request parameter into GWT MainEntryPoint client class?

Tags: java, facebook, gwt

I am having a facebook app which on loading will load my GWT application in the canvas. I am just loading the main page that will load the MainEntryPoint class which is a client class.

I dont have access to the signed_request parameter in this class. How to get that parameter?

Otherwise should I call a server side method? How can I call a server side method/implementation or make a RPC call from canvas url?

Can anyone please help me? Thank you all in advance. Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signed_request parameter is passed to your server as a post parameter.
the easy way would be to render it in the GWT hosting page as a javascript parameter.

this approach is wrong.

signed_request is meant to be validated on your server with your applications secret key. be careful not to expose your secret key to the client in the GWT code, where it can be read and abused.

try using the facebook javascript SDK.

[`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) and [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) are good starting points.

since you're using GWT call native javascript code